# Still apache page running after configuring nginx?

Tags: server, apache2, nginx

I have done all the below steps still apache page is running on localhost:8000 :

It is because by default Apache and nginx are listening to the same port number (:80)

Reconfigure nginx to listen on a different port by following these steps:

```
sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Change all ports :80 to :8000 or another unused port number.
Check if the configuration is correct:

```
sudo service nginx configtest
```

Restart nginx:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Check the status of nginx:

```
sudo service nginx status
```

Note: You can also check on your browser whether nginx is working:

http://localhost:8000

Answer (score 1):

Then just stop apache service

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

and remove it from autostart with

```
sudo update-rc.d -f  apache2 remove
```

Not sure if that is, what you wanted...

Also to list current processes listening on port 80 or 8000:

```
lsof -i :80
```

or

```
lsof -i :8000
```